# Java - Lookup table, array, switch vs if considering computational time

Tags: java

Let's consider a game such as rock, scissor, paper. In this case I can draw a binary map with the winning solution and store the map and create a look up table, however I think there are multiple strategies on how to do it:

- A series of if statements
- An array and check if the solution is in the array
- A switch statement

What is the best way to create a look up table for such a problem?
For best way I mean the most computational and memory efficient way, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Balance KISS with YAGNI. Make it exactly as simple as you need it.

I'm sure you could create a solution using entirely bit-shifting if you needed thousands of calculations per second on a single CPU... but you probably don't.

A nicely encapsulated, readable class using simple `if` statements and written for scalability would do fine in 99% of cases.